# Write for loop as boolean operation

Tags: matlab, boolean

**Problem Statement**

I want to improve the speed of my code which has a lot of for-loops in the following manner. A programmer I talked to on a meeting mentioned that boolean operations in matlab work faster then for loops (sorry I am not a programmer, so if I am wrong please tell me).

I have multiple loops which are similar to this:

```
for k= 1:length(source);
    kk=source(1,k);
    E(find(E(:,2)==kk),3)=0;

end
```

**What I try to achieve with this loop**

With this loop i want to find all values in the second column of E which are equal to the values in source. And in the rows where i find the values in the second column i want to set the third column to zero.

**Question**
Is there a way to write this as a matlab boolean matrix operation ? Or is there another way to improve the coding to improve the speed of these kinds of short for-loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation, you basically want to find all rows in column 2 that are in the `source` array and set them equal to `0`. You can use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to check if items in one array are within another. It will return a logical array the size of the first input that is `1` when the item was found in the second input and `0` otherwise.

```
% Figure out which rows of E(:,2) contain a value that exists in source
tf = ismember(E(:,2), source);
```

This logical array (`tf`) tells us which rows of `E` we want to set to `0`. We can use this variable as the first subscript (row) and then we want to specify column    `3` as the second subscript of the assignment.

```
% Set these rows (at column 3) equal to 0
E(tf, 3) = 0;
```

**Side-note**

In the solution above, we completely eliminated the for loop. This isn't always possible. In your case, if we couldn't remove the loop, we could at least remove `find` to speed some things up. This is because `E(:,2) == k` will yield a logical matrix that we can use *directly* as the first subscript in the assignment. There is no need for `find`. Logical indexing is *always* going to be faster than `find`.

```
E(E(:,2) == k, 3) = 0;
```